# How many visitors can 20 concurrent connections handle?

Tags: web-hosting

I have a shared hosting service and the maximum concurrent connection (Entry Process) given is 20, I was wondering how many visitors this can handle? Page load time is up to 2s (the closer to the server the faster). Can anyone give me a rough computation or teach me how to compute it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a small but important difference between the `concurrent connections (Entry Process)` and `the number of visitors allowed to view your website`.

Entry Process only counts the users who are actively downloading content from your website. Once user finishes the loading of a page content, its connection (Entry process) is released for other users.

Having said that, if your web page takes 2 seconds to fully load, it counts as one entry process in use for 2 seconds only, unless visitor clicks on any other page that establishes another connection.

That means, a good number of visitors can view your site concurrently as long as they don't make all requests simultaneously.

You can calculate how many visitors per minute you can serve if you know your site's average load time and Entry Processes.

Say for example, you have hosting account with 20 Entry Processes and a website with average page load of 2 seconds.

**Entry Processes per second** = (Total No. of Entry Processes / seconds) 
=> 20/2 
=> 10

In this example , you'll have 10 Entry Processes per second to serve visitors. Roughly, your hosting account can serve 8 to 10 concurrent visitors per second purely based on their browsing pattern.

**Entry Processes per minute** = (Total No. of Entry Processes / seconds * 60 seconds) 
=> 10 * 60 
=> 600

You'll have 600 Entry Processes per minute to serve visitors. Roughly, your hosting account can serve 500 to 600 concurrent visitors per minute purely based on their browsing pattern.